# basic - post on wall (from apps tutorial) now showing message

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

using the basic example, 
working fine - but not showing message.
any ideas?

```
     $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

     $message = "Apps on Facebook.com are cool!";

     $feed_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
            . "&message=" . $message;

     if (empty($_REQUEST["post_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $feed_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
        echo ("Feed Post Id: " . $_REQUEST["post_id"]);
     }
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in documentation of [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)
message parameter is ignored from July 12, 2011.